# Компактное создание словаря из списка

Tags: c#

Есть список и словарь вида

```
List<string> from = new List<string>( new string[] { "1", "2", "3" });
Dictionary<string, object> to = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Для каждого элемента списка, который используется как ключ, создается объект и помещается в словарь.

```
foreach (var f in from)
{
    to.Add(f, new Object());
}
```

Можно ли сократить код так, чтобы инициализация словаря происходила одной строкой (после объявления переменной)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dict = new List<string>( new string[] { "1", "2", "3" }).ToDictionary(el=>el, el=>new Object());
```

[C# ToDictionary Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/todictionary)